# Couldn't render images from Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have build a web application using Mongo Db and Express Js. With the usage of Multar library I have saved the images to MongoDb as a Base64 object. I couldn't render it to my HTML image page. Could someone help me with this?

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
const services = require('../services/render');
const AuthController = require('../controller/authController');
const Accomodation = require('../model/accomodation');
const multer = require('multer');
const mongooseValidationErrorHandler = require('mongoose-validation-error-message-handler');
const accomodation = require('../model/accomodation');
const { off } = require('../model/serviceProvider');


// image upload
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({storage:storage});



// Accomdation inserting 
route.post('/add-accomodation', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) =>{
    const accomodation = new Accomodation({
    serviceProvider:req.body.serviceProvider,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    otherdesc: req.body.otherdesc,
    location: req.body.location,
    image: {
        data: req.file.buffer,
        contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    price: req.body.price,
    category: req.body.category,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    availabilty: req.body.availabilty,


   
 
    });

    

    
    await accomodation.save(accomodation)
    .then(data=> {
        
        req.session.message= {
            type: 'Success',
            message: 'Service created successfully'
        }; res.redirect('/dashboard/accomodation');

        
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        const error = mongooseValidationErrorHandler(err);
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message:err.message || "Error in creating"
        })
    })
  
})


/**
 * @description Root route
 * @method GET
 */
route.get('/dashboard/accomodation', async (req, res)=>{

    if(req.query.id){
        const id = req.query.id;
        await Accomodation.findById(id).then(data=>
            {
                if(!data){
                    res.status(404).send({message: "Service not Found"})
                }else{
                    res.send(data)
                }
                
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                res.status(500).send({message: "Error retrieving service by ID"})
            })
    }else{
        Accomodation.find().then(accomodation=>{
            res.render('accomodation', {title: 'Accomodations- Leisure Diary', accomodation: accomodation});
            
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({message:err.message || "Error on getting all the data"});
        })
    }

 });

//  add new accomodation
route.get('/create-accomodation', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('create-accomodation', {title: 'Create New Accomodation'} )
})


 module.exports = route;
```

**HTML page**

```
<%  for(var i = 0; i<accomodation.length; i++){ %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                                    <!-- '/uploads/' + accomodation[i].image %> -->
                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <% if (accomodation.image) { %>
                                            
                                            <img src="data:<%= accomodation[i].image.contentType %>;base64,<%= accomodation[i].image.data.toString('base64') %>" width="100" />
                                            <% } else { %>
                                            No Image
                                            <% } %>
```

Result always shows **No Image  **

**Model**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

const AccomodationModel = new Schema({

```
serviceProvider: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},

title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
otherdesc: {
    type: String,
    
},
location: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
image: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType:String,
    
},
price: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},

availabilty: {
    type: Date,
},

created:{
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
}
```

},{collection: 'Accomodation'}, {timestamps: true}
);

// Accomodation is the model here
module.exports =mongoose.model('Accomodation', AccomodationModel);

Could someone point me the mistake in rendering the images to HTML page